# Python\PySpark Reg Expression - replace a pattern IF it occurs x time in string

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

my strings look something like this :

- **ABS25C**/18033C,**25A**/17972C
- **ABS300ABC**
- **AS25C**/18033C,**25A**/17972C,**25B**/18026C

desired output :

- ABS25C25A
- ABS300ABC
- AS25C25A25B

I have tried many different combinations. It seems straight forward. (/.+,) would match those characters between the "/" and ",". I would then be able to replace them with empty string.

But it ignores the first "," and therefore returns the string I want in the middle. Meaning it would get replaced if I went that route.

example in image. I end up losing out on text I need. I figured there was a way to get what I need via straight regex and not have to split(",") the string then do regex

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
/[^/,\n]+,?
```

And replace using empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m2QeZh/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `/`: Match a `/`
- `[^/,\n]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that is not `/` and `,` and not a line break
- `,?`: Match optional `,`

Comment: awesome, thanks! I will have to practice implementation of patterns like this.